# ubuntu server PS, ifocnfig, command not working

Tags: command, ps

i am working on ubuntu server from past few months 
and now suddenly ps, ifconfing commnad stop working with below error.

user1@Fb1:/usr/bin$    ps
-bash: /bin/ps: No such file or directory

any suggestions to get this command working back.

Comment: This might be better off migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of `which ps` and `ls /usr/bin -al` (which are both in /bin also)? Does it work if you gain root privileges, either using `sudo ifconfig` or `sudo su`, then `ifconfig`?

This is possibly an issue with file permissions but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: as requested i loged in as root

root@Fb1:~# ps
-su: /bin/ps: No such file or directory


user1@Fb1:/usr/sbin$ which ps
/bin/ps

ls /usr/bin -al
i do not find ps file there 

pls help i will reply to all your answers

Comment: I meant for you to run `ls /usr/bin -al` separately so we can see if the files ("ps", "ifconfig") are there, and if they are, what their file permissions are. I have to guess at this point that either those files in /bin aren't there at all, or cannot be executed due to messed up permissions. I'm hoping for the latter, because that can probably be resolved without too much hassle. :)

Naturally, if /bin is empty you're going to have a hard time running the commands that are in /bin, so share the output of each command so we'll get a better idea..

Answer (score 0):

First use *locate* to find your *ps* or *ifconfig* program:

```
$ locate ps | grep bin
```

Also you may try *whereis* command:

```
$ whereis ps
```

---

If you don't find them, try to search as root user.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to put all the outputs of different commnads as below
root@Fb1:/usr/bin# whereis ps
ps: /bin/ps /usr/share/man/man1/ps.1.gz

root@Fb1:/usr/bin# ls -lsa ps
16 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15859 2010-05-26 12:21 ps

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your $PATH I suspect it doesn't have /sbin ..   maybe new software  overwrite your $PATH..

normal path should be include this (mebada is my user name)

```
mebada@T430:~$ echo $PATH
/home/mebada/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```